# Significato di "in isghembo"

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L'isola*, di Giani Stuparich, ho letto:

> La stanza era carica di mobili, di tappeti, di stuoie: vecchie porcellane inglesi, ninnoli del Giappone, dell'India, stampe, modellini di velieri, conchiglie esotiche. Una specie di *bazar*: la caratteristica casa dei navigatori di lungo corso. E quel pretino dell'aria meschina e col volto affilato **in isghembo** sul petto, faceva un penoso contrasto in mezzo a tutti quei ricordi di lontane navigazioni; come se il tronco robusto della famiglia, abituato alle tempeste e ai pericoli, si fosse a un certo punto spezzato e ne germogliasse ora un esile ramicciolo, pavido d'ogni vento.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato della locuzione "in isghembo" che appare in questo brano? Non ho trovato la voce "isghembo" su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Ho invece visto questa espressione su [questo libro Ottocentesco](https://books.google.es/books?id=tU9mAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=isghembo&source=bl&ots=u86RGdHKlM&sig=ACfU3U2W5eMo-Rda2TcT3ervxx8CgLOTRw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy19XNvb3hAhVtzoUKHfMlA3cQ6AEwBnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=isghembo&f=false). Si tratta di un termine arcaico?

Comment: È una forma arcaica per indicare "sghembo" ovvero "storto" http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sghembo/. Noto anche che in quest'altro libro di architettura si utilizza il termine "in isquadra" https://books.google.it/books?id=0_FDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=isquadra&source=bl&ots=34j7zg7DCX&sig=ACfU3U2LTFuWtuYzkim494TiIaF9QfTWYg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3p_TQyr3hAhUlmeAKHUGEAjUQ6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=isquadra&f=false.

Comment: Non conosco le regole ortografiche del XIX secolo, azzardo che la "i" venga aggiunta come forma di "pausa" nella pronuncia per non avere tre consonanti di fila ("n" "s" "g")

Comment: Più o meno, @RiccardoDeContardi. Più che ortografia, è una questione fonetica, e quella “i” prostetica (tipica di espressioni come “in Ispagna”, cf. _Don Giovanni_) è detta spesso appunto “eufonica”.

Comment: Io la conoscevo sotto il nome di ["i epentetica"](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epentesi), anche se forse quello è un termine più generale che indica l'inserzione di *i* in molti nessi consonantici (e.g. "fantasima" per "fantasma"). Si tratta di un fenomeno molto comune nelle lingue romanze (cfr. il francese schola>escole>école) ma che in italiano è andato sempre più in disuso (probabilmente per influenza delle varietà settentrionali, da sempre più tolleranti dei nessi consonantici).

Comment: Da sottolineare inoltre che spesso tali vocaboli, purché arcaici, vengono trovati nel dialetto parlato. A Livorno mi é sovente capitato di sentire "ischerzo", ad esempio.

Comment: @Easymode44: È possibile che Stuparich volesse riprodurre qualche parlato regionale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non troverai sui dizionari nemmeno *ispecie*. Be', no, [c'è](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ispecie/)! C'è anche [*isbaglio*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/isbaglio/). I lemmi principali sono *specie* e *sbaglio* che per molto tempo la norma prevedeva dovessero prendere la “i prostetica” per facilitare la pronuncia di ‘n’ o ‘r’ seguite da ‘s impura’.

Lo stesso fenomeno si incontra in francese, castigliano, catalano e portoghese, con la vocale prostetica ‘e’, che in quasi tutti i casi è diventata parte della parola: “España”, “école” sono i primi esempi che vengono in mente.

Il dizionario Treccani non riporta “iscuola”, che però compare [spesso](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_it&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=iscuola&num=10) in letteratura.

Nel tuo caso si tratta di [*sghembo*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sghembo/), qui vale *obliquamente*.

Il fenomeno, in italiano, va scomparendo e scrivere la “i prostetica” è in molti casi affettato. La locuzione “per iscritto” è da considerare cristallizzata.